# How to add class on scroll in Angular

Tags: angular, scroll, ng-class

Just learning Angular again. Installed AngularCLI and am trying to add a class on scroll from what I had before using jquery. Do I need to use [ngClass] to check a variable with window location? I am trying to use @HostListener right now.

```
$(function () {
 $(document).scroll(function () {
   $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
 });
});

$(function() {
 $(document).scroll(function() {
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (x > 3300) {
    $nav.removeClass('scrolled');
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
import { Component, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 ||     
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.getElementById('subTitle').classList.add('red');
      document.getElementById('paragraph').classList.add('green');
    }
  }
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

See live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changeclassonscroll

Answer (score 8):

The above solutions work, but I think it's cleaner and more appropriate to utilize the framework as much as possible.

Typescript file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    scrolled: boolean = false;

    @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
    onWindowScroll() {
        this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ className: scrolled }"></div>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer - the document.ElementById pure JS solution is anti pattern eventhough it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside the class

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
onWindowScroll(event: Event) {
    //set up the div "id=nav"
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 3300 ||
        document.documentElement.scrollTop > 3300) {
        document.getElementById('nav').classList.add('scrolled');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('nav').classList.remove('scrolled');
        this.innerWidth = 'auto';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add import on your typeScript file on top

```
{import {Component,HostListener,Directive,HostBinding,Input} from '@angular/core';}
```

then in app.components.ts for general scroll

add

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  scrolled: boolean = false;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
      this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
  }
}
```

then add

[ngClass]="{ 'scroll-add' : scrolled }"